# How to create password recovery if the password in database is hash?

Tags: c#

```
protected void btnPass_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
 //Create Connection String And SQL Statement 
 string strConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString; 
 string strSelect = "SELECT UserName,Password FROM Users WHERE Email = @Email"; 


 SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strConnection); 
 SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(); 
 command.Connection = connection; 
 command.CommandType = CommandType.Text; 
 command.CommandText = strSelect; 


SqlParameter email = new SqlParameter("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50); 
 email.Value = txtEmail.Text.Trim().ToString(); 
 command.Parameters.Add(email); 


 //Create Dataset to store results and DataAdapter to fill Dataset 
 DataSet dsPwd = new DataSet(); 
 SqlDataAdapter dAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command); 
connection.Open(); 
 dAdapter.Fill(dsPwd); 
 connection.Close(); 
 if(dsPwd.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0 ) 
     { 
 MailMessage loginInfo = new MailMessage(); 
 loginInfo.To.Add(txtEmail.Text.ToString()); 
 loginInfo.From = new MailAddress("YourID@gmail.com"); 
 loginInfo.Subject = "Forgot Password Information"; 


 loginInfo.Body = "Username: " + dsPwd.Tables[0].Rows[0]["UserName"] + "

Password: " + dsPwd.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Password"] + "

"; 
 loginInfo.IsBodyHtml = true; 
 SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(); 
 smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; 
 smtp.Port = 587; 
 smtp.EnableSsl = true; 
 smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("YourGmailID@gmail.com", "YourGmailPassword"); 
 smtp.Send(loginInfo); 
 lblMessage.Text = "Password is sent to you email id,you can now Login"; 
 } 
 else 
 { 
 lblMessage.Text = "Email Address Not Registered"; 
 } 


 }:
```

Comment: Your post is unreadable. But for the question if you store hash you don't provide password recovery. You provide safe way to change password to new one.

Comment: Please don't post code with line numbers in it

Answer (score 2):

part of the point of hashing is that it is generally difficult to reverse.
It would be a bad idea to let someone see a forgotten password, instead you should consider creating a page where a user can "reset" there password to something new. Alternatively you could set there password to a known value, then send them the new password with instructions to change the password once they are logged in.